# Will Xorg 1.13 land in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics, 12.10

I am asking this because there may be some Optimus Nvidia updates before next year April ubuntu release and i read somewhere its connected with 1.13 features? Or i am maybe wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Quantal ships with Xorg 1.13 RC5 it is likely that it will ship the final X 1.13 version.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/xserver-xorg-core - 2:1.12.99.905-0ubuntu3

Even if it does not ship the final 1.13 (which is very unlikely), you won't have to worry about missing PRIME features as these are already merged with rc5.

You may also be interested in the tracker for hybrid graphic technologies like Optimus: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-q-hybrid-graphics

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/xorg/1:7.7+1ubuntu3) is the `xorg` package landing in 12.10 as of now.

The naming convention they use (`1:7.7+1ubuntu3`) appears to be different from the one you are using but maybe you can look though the change logs for the features you are waiting for.

Hope this helps.